# get size of QGraphicsView from QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, size, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

**Q**: How can I get  `graphicsview` `width` and `height` from my own `graphicsItem` that subclass from `QGraphicsItem` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that there is only one view of your scene:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class SimpleItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    QRectF boundingRect() const
    {
        qreal penWidth = 1;
        return QRectF(-10 - penWidth / 2, -10 - penWidth / 2, 20 + penWidth, 20 + penWidth);
    }

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
    {
        QGraphicsView *view = scene()->views().first();
        qDebug() << "View width:" << view->width() << "height:" << view->height();
        painter->drawRect(-10, -10, 20, 20);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsView view;
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    scene->addItem(new SimpleItem());
    view.setScene(scene);
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

See [QGraphicsItem::scene()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#scene) and [QGraphicsScene::views()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#views).